# d3d9 render animated cursor is slow

Tags: direct3d, directx-9

i use d3d9 to draw a animated cursor.

first i load the animated cursor frome a texture, and i create two 32*32 offscreen plain surface suf1_, suf2_.

every frame, i update the cursor rect in the texture, then

```
D3DXLoadSurfaceFromSurface(suf1_, 0, 0, textureSurface, 0, rect, D3DX_DEFAULT, 0);
device->SetCursorProperties(0, 0, suf2_);

std::swap(suf1_, suf2_);
```

but it's too slow.

so how to make it fast? any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you better have multiple surfaces for all animation frames and set them as cursor sequentially